# How to sort 2 rows of data using 1 row as it's reference?

Tags: python, sorting

I currently have 2 rows of data in one array, 1 with values and 1 with index positions from another dataset. I would like to sort these two rows by the values (ascending) row only while keeping its respective index attached.

(The index rows are not 0,1,2,3 etc they are 0,18,21 etc)

Comment: You can pass a key function to `sort()` that allows you to determine the order to your liking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Show the code. Provide the sample dataset. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) before asking a question to get better response from SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
indexes = [ ... ]
values = [ ... ]

values_sorted, indexes_sorted = zip(*sorted(zip(values, indexes)))
```

More about [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

More about [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Answer (score 2):

from [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting):

```
data = [('red', 1), ('blue', 1), ('red', 2), ('blue', 2)]
sorted(data, key=itemgetter(0))
```

> > > [('blue', 1), ('blue', 2), ('red', 1), ('red', 2)]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have array like this:

```
[[4, 29, 24, 3, 19, 21, 10, 7, 8, 6],
 [57, 582, 855, 383, 269, 992, 967, 815, 222, 403]]
```

You can use the following code:

```
import copy
mappings = dict(zip(x[1],x[0]))
sorted_values = sorted(copy.deepcopy(x[1]))
new_array = [[mappings[value] for value in sorted_values] , sorted_values]
print(new_array)
```

O/P:

```
[[4, 8, 19, 3, 6, 29, 7, 24, 10, 21],
 [57, 222, 269, 383, 403, 582, 815, 855, 967, 992]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question i assume the following is the data which you want to merge and sort

```
firstArr = [[3,6,8,2],[1,7,9,6]]
secondArr = [3,6,78,4,2,7,9,5,34,56]
```

You can use the below code to do that

```
def merge2Arrays(firstArr,secondArr):
    result = firstArr[0:1][0]
    for i in firstArr[1:2][0]:
        result.append(secondArr[i])
    result.sort()
    print(result)

Output :  [2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 56]
```